# How to check that you can read S3 object?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, acl

I have an object in S3 bucket that I can list but when I am trying to read it it fails on Access denied.

I would like to check somehow that its readable. Checking via trying to getObject() is not an option as in positive case it will transfer the object which is big. And I want to avoid the unnecessary transfer(The data files are 10 - 200 MBs).

I am looking into getObjectAcl() and processing the result of it. But I am wondering whether there is something more straightforward.

Its in java using the AmazonS3Client

Answer (score 0):

The possible permission with reference to Object are given below

```
Read: Authorized user can download the file.
Write: Authorized user can replace the file or delete it.
Read ACP: Authorized user can list ACL of that file.
Write ACP: Authorized user can modify the ACL of the file.
```

Could you please check whether you have the right permission or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [getObjectMetadata(bucketName, key)](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/85d0cffc3b243db9f5ca9da20e3b1298bb174c0f/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L815) method.